# mysql where condition priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and it gets the first result "Edit: of each contact" as I want but I do not need any other results per contact after. So example if they have 3 phone # and one is main, it gives me the main then the other 2. I have tried grouping but it ends up getting the first one pulled no matter if main or not. Any thoughts to how I could do this without doing a php check in the loop for if contact already exists?

```
SELECT pc.firstname, pc.lastname, pp.areacode, pp.prefix, pp.last4
, if(pc.mainphone = pp.phoneid,1,0) as phone_priority
FROM contacts pc
JOIN phone pp ON ( (pp.contid = pc.contid && pp.phoneid = pc.mainphone) || (pp.contid = pc.contid) )
ORDER BY pc.lastname ASC, pc.firstname ASC, phone_priority DESC
```

Table setup:

```
contacts (id, firstname, lastname, mainphone)
phone (id, areacode, prefix, last4)
```

Using MySQL 4.

Comment: Can not use limit. I need to interate through the complete list of contacts.

Comment: JOIN or LEFT JOIN; does not make a difference because of the || "or" statement part

Comment: When using a left join remove the || part of the criteria.

Comment: Can not change/remove ||. I need to see if mainphone exist first else find the first phone number. That is why the || is there. If i take the || out then it only finds main and does do the check if a phone just exist.

Comment: @David What to show if there is no mainphone in phone table?

Comment: The first # that comes up in the phone table by contid. See that is why I did this. ( (pp.contid = pc.contid && pp.phoneid = pc.mainphone) || (pp.contid = pc.contid) ). Check and see if main phone exist or if a number exist period for the contid. I am trying to get mainphone first then any after and I am doing that with the above query but I do not need all. I just need the first one per contid "contact". So if main exist display and continue without any. If main doesnt exist get first of any in list. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Use a LIMIT expression to narrow the result set down to the first result. See [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) for details.

Comment: Should not this be a comment?

Comment: No. Why do you think it should be a comment?

Comment: @Shakti: I agree with Oswald. While sometimes it is appropriate to post a link that may help as a comment, if it is in fact an answer to the question, it should be posted as an answer so that it can be marked as such. Makes it much easier for others who come to the page to immediately find the answer without having to read through non germane text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT pc.firstname, 
    pc.lastname, 
    pp.areacode, 
    pp.prefix, 
    pp.last4 , 
    CASE 
        WHEN pp.mainphone IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
 END    AS phone_priority 
FROM contacts pc LEFT JOIN phone pp 
    ON pp.contid = pc.contid 
 AND pp.phoneid = pc.mainphone
 ORDER BY pc.lastname ASC, pc.firstname ASC, phone_priority DESC
```

Comment: I still need to pull a phone if main does not exist but a phone exist. So first checking main exist if doesnt get any phone else no phone. As said my query works its just pulling main first then non mains after. I need to limit per contact one result. If main it be the listed one, if not which ever phone comes first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant -

```
SELECT t.contid
     , t.firstname
     , t.lastname
     , if(t.phoneid IS NULL, p2.phoneid, t.phoneid) phone
     , if(t.phoneid IS NULL, p2.areacode, t.areacode) areacode
     , if(t.phoneid IS NULL, p2.prefix, t.prefix) prefix
     , if(t.phoneid IS NULL, p2.last4, t.last4) last4

FROM
  (
  SELECT c.contid
       , c.firstname
       , c.lastname
       , c.mainphone
       , p.phoneid
       , p.areacode
       , p.prefix
       , p.last4

  FROM
    contacts c
  LEFT JOIN phone p
    ON c.contid = p.contid AND c.mainphone = p.phoneid) t
LEFT JOIN phone p2
  ON t.contid = p2.contid AND t.mainphone <> p2.phoneid
GROUP BY
  t.contid
```